# TOAD SQL - LPAD Number, but also add decimals?

Tags: sql, decimal, toad, cellpadding

Basically what I'm trying to do is add '000' to a number (between 5-8 characters in length) and make the whole numbers have decimals.

What I came up with is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 '000' || TO_CHAR(Blah, '9,999,999.99') AS "Data"
FROM Blah database
```

While this does what I ideally want, there is **a gap** between the zeroes of either 3 or 4 depending on the number. Obviously I don't want the gap there. Where am I going astray?

Answer (score 0):

Use trim(to_char(x, '9,999,999.99')) this way you will avoid gap